# PHP ajax process 404 page not found error before complete the process

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I am using a PHP ajax function to load the Twitter followers using Twitter API into database,In the case of large number of followers.it takes longtime for processing and before completion of the process 404 page not found error is occurred.

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can rise the time that a script is allowed to execute:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php

Give attention to your max_execution_time in php.ini

But i wouldnt suggest if you are doing this in the frontend then it sounds more like an performance problem of your script. No user want to wait more than 4 seconds for website. Also 2 seconds are too long.

Comment: I already set the set_time_limit(0) at the begining of the php file and i am trying to integrate this functionality in smarty

Comment: try to set max_execution_time to 0 in php.ini to try if it works. Otherwise it isnt a time problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase execution time. It can be done in 2 ways

1. Set the value in script
2. Set the value in php.ini file

> **Set the value in your script**
>
> ```
> ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
> ```

Copy and paste the above code in to your applications config file or index.php or on a specified file.

> **Set the value in php.ini file**
>
> Open your php.ini file in notepad. Search for the string **max_execution_time**. Change its value into 300.
> (You can find the file in your c:/wamp/bin/php folder)

Comment: I set the ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); but still i can see the same issue.  Any other methods to solve the issue ?

Comment: I thing there may be some bugs in your code. This may occur due to the execution of a non ending loop. Check the code first. Or increase the max_execution_time value. Try to set it in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been tested it with set max_execution_time  to 0 still I found the issue. I guess the issue is related to Apache server timeout. I  echo 'something' after each insertion to the database and it's working.

Sametime I found another issue on the front end page, "Internal server error 500" but still ajax process for insertion is progressing.